# $\{x_{nk}\}$ is any subsequence of $\{x_n\}$, prove the order of their limsup and liminf

Tags: real-analysis

$\{x_{n_k}\}$ is any subsequence of $\{x_n\}$, prove that $$\liminf_{n\to\infty}x_n \leq \liminf_{n\to\infty}x_{n_k} \leq \limsup_{n\to\infty}x_{n_k} \leq \limsup_{n\to\infty}x_n$$
The solution says that one only need to prove $\liminf_{n\to\infty}x_n \leq \liminf_{n\to\infty}x_{n_k}$, and the other half of the statement can be proved by using $\liminf_{n\to\infty}-x_n = -\limsup_{n\to\infty} x_n$. But I don't know how to use the equation to prove the other half. Any help, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question specifically:

If we have proved the first half then we know for any sequence $x_n$,

$$\lim\inf_{n \rightarrow \infty} x_n \leq \lim \inf_{n \rightarrow \infty} x_{n_k}$$

It follows that:
$$\lim\inf_{n \rightarrow \infty} -x_n \leq \lim \inf_{n \rightarrow \infty} -x_{n_k}$$

Using the identity:

$$-\lim\sup_{n \rightarrow \infty} x_n \leq  -\lim \sup_{n \rightarrow \infty} x_{n_k}$$

Hence:

$$\lim\sup_{n \rightarrow \infty} x_n \geq \lim \sup_{n \rightarrow \infty} x_{n_k}$$

Comment: Thanks, why $\lim\inf_{n \rightarrow \infty} -x_n \leq \lim \inf_{n \rightarrow \infty} -x_{n_k}$

Comment: Because in the first part you proved that holds for any sequence (x_n). Hence, specifically, it holds for (-x_n).

Comment: Thanks so much! Sorry for such a dumb question.

Answer (score 0):

It is obvious that $\lim\inf x_n\leq\lim\sup x_n$ and $\lim\inf x_{nk}\leq\lim\sup x_{nk}$. So, if we show that $\lim\inf x_n\leq\lim\inf x_{nk}$, by symmetric logic, $\lim\sup x_n\geq\lim\sup x_{nk}$ and we'll be done.

Note that a definition of $\lim\inf$ is the following

1. There exists a subsequence that converges to the $\lim\inf$
2. For any number $m$ less than the $\lim\inf$, there are only a finite number of elements of the sequence that are lower than $m$.

So, if we show condition 1 holding for $x_{nk}\to$ condition 1 holding for $x_n$, we are done. But, that is obvious since a subsequence of $x_{nk}$ is a subsequence of $x_n$. So we are done.

Comment: But it says to use $\liminf_{n\to\infty}-x_n = -\limsup_{n\to\infty} x_n$